# Can anyone tell why this switch statement is not working and always go to the Default case in javascript?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

```
switch (document.getElementById("box").style.borderBottomColor.value) {
    case "#0000FF":
        document.getElementById("box").style = "margin:25px; height:0; width:0; border-left:75px solid #0000FF; border-right:75px solid #0000FF; border-top:75px solid #0000FF; border-bottom:75px solid #0000FF; border-radius:50%";
        break;

    default:
        document.getElementById("box").style = CircleStyle;

    }
```

Comment: You can’t set strings to the `style` property. Read [the MDN docs on `style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Setting_styles): _“Styles should not be set by assigning a string directly to the `style` property (as in `elt.style = "color: blue;"`), since it is considered read-only, as the `style` attribute returns a [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration) object which is also read-only. Instead, styles can be set by assigning values to the properties of `style`.”_

Answer (score 2):

It goes to the default case because `document.getElementById("box").style.borderBottomColor` is a string, when set, and doesn't have a `value` property.

Also, as a side note, beware that unless you set the specific property through the style explicitly, you would have to get the [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) in order to get the property's initial value set in your CSS code.

Finally, although not related to your question, the way you set your styles is wrong. You can't set a string to the `style` object – which is read-only by the way –  the way you do in the `style` attribute in HTML. You must set the property you want as a property of the `style` object directly. Check out [Xufox's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690065/can-anyone-tell-why-this-switch-statement-is-not-working-and-always-go-to-the-de/51690086#comment90342007_51690065) under your post as it provides some useful links for you to check out.

**Correct Example:**

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");

switch (box.style.borderBottomColor) {
    case "#0000FF":
        box.style.margin = "25px";
        box.style.height = 0;
        //...
        break;

    default:
        box.style.margin = 0;
        box.style.height = "auto";
}
```

Comment: Hey Angeli, thanks for your comment. However, I do not think that is the issue because I declared the below variables:

var DefaultStyle = "margin:25px; height:0; width:0; border-left:75px solid #FFA500; border-right:75px solid #FFA500; border-top:75px solid #FFA500; border-bottom:75px solid #FFA500";

var TriangleStyle = "margin:25px; height:0; width:0; border-left:75px solid transparent; border-right:75px solid transparent; border-top:0; border-bottom:150px solid #FFA500" ;

var CircleStyle =  DefaultStyle + ";border-radius:50%";

Comment: It doesn't matter what variables you have declared, because `value` is a **non-existent** property of `document.getElementById("box").style.borderBottomColor`, so it won't ever be `#0000FF` or whatever you set. And even if that weren't a problem, you aren't allowed to set the `style` object.

Comment: Hey Angeli, thanks for your comment. However, I do not think that is the issue because I declared the variable CircleStyle that way.
And if the CircleStyle variable value works then the case 1 should work as well. I believe the issue is with the switch expression I made and Case 1 value. BUt I cannot figure out whats wrong with that..Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I will check your corrected code and advise. Thanks for the quick responses. :)

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to share, the following corrected the code. Thanks for your idea on Computed Style method as I dug into that further after you suggested.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("box");

switch (window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("border-bottom-color")){                                          

    case 'rgb(0, 0, 255)':

          elem.style = "margin:25px; height:0; width:0; border-left:75px solid #0000FF; border-right:75px solid #0000FF; border-top:75px solid #0000FF; border-bottom:75px solid #0000FF; border-radius:50%";
    break;

    default:
          elem.style = CircleStyle;

}
```

Comment: Your code is wrong, @Shahriar. You're not allowed to set the `elem.style` object because it's a read-only property, let alone set it to a string. Even if it somehow works on the browser you're testing, it's extremely bad practice and you shouldn't share it, because it will confuse others that may stumble upon your answer.